# How to scan for interference due to _wide_ Wifi channels (40, 80 Mhz)

Tags: linux, wifi

I can use `iwlist $DEV scan` to find the *base* frequency used by neighbouring APs, and avoid them.

How do I find any secondary frequencies which they use for extended 40 and 80 Mhz channels, to avoid these secondary frequencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember `iwlist` is deprecated!  Use the `iw` tool.

```
iw dev wlan0 scan
...
    HT operation:
     * primary channel: 6
     * secondary channel offset: no secondary
     * STA channel width: 20 MHz
```

Answer (score 0):

The default max channel with of 20MHz supports a max speed of 130Mbps. Increasing this to 40MHz will increase the maximum theoretical speed to 300Mbps.

The catch is that in areas with a lot of wifi traffic (and Bluetooth etc. which share the same radio frequencies), 40MHz may decrease your overall speed. Devices should detect interference when using 40MHz , and drop back to 20MHz.

Edit the file `/etc/config/wireless`, and restart the wifi AP by executing the following commands:

-> example is name of your device

```
  uci set wireless.example.htmode=HT40+  # or: HT40- if using channel 11
  uci commit wireless; wifi
```

Note that option 'htmode' should be set to either `HT40+` (for channels 1-7) or `HT40-` (for channels 5-11) or simply `HT40` on versions >= to 14.07.

You have to use WPA2 encryption with AES.